# open whatsapp from webview controller xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, webview, whatsapp

I am using webview for my swift app and i have share on WhatsApp button in my website, which works fine on browser, But on iPhone app when i click on WhatsApp share button, nothing happens, I have also created a android app with same website and i added this code to my app so WhatsApp share works..

```
if (url != null && url.startsWith("whatsapp://")) {
        view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
```

How to open WhatsApp from my app, I am using Xcode 8 and iOS 10

This is my webview app:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use URL schemas to open whatsapp from your app.

```
class myViewController : UIViewController,UIWebViewDelegate{

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

let url = NSURL(string:"m.wahstatus.com/ws/punjabi-status/")
let request = NSURLRequest (url: url! as URL)
webView.frame = self.view.frame; webView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
webView.delegate = self

}

func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    if (request.URL.scheme == "whatsapp") {
       let wurl = URL(string: "whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!")! 
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) { 
UIApplication.shared.open(wurl, options: [:], completionHandler: nil) 
} else { UIApplication.shared.openURL(wurl) 
} 
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Ref  https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013  for sending media tyoe and other usage.

Comment: i dont think it will work on webview, bcz this is what i use in my html page.

<a href="whatsapp://send" data-text="" class="wa_btn wa_btn_s" style="display:none">Share </a>

this is what i want to open through my ios app, this code is in my webview

Comment: I use it and it works, did you check that link ? whatsapp also recommends this . Give this a try, whatsapp uses URL schema.

Comment: Handel heref in webview's delegate and open whatsapp using URL schema

Comment: how to handle webview's delegate ? and how to use url schema ? i already tried edited my info.plist but not worked, please can you expain ?

Comment: there is not LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in my info.plist

Comment: i have used your code, but the problem is it does not load webview, when i open my app it redirect me to whatsapp, please help me

Comment: Use webview's shouldStartLoadWithRequest delegate to handle your href. And call openURL there

Comment: Post your code where you initialize and load webview

Comment: let url = NSURL(string:"http://m.wahstatus.com/ws/punjabi-status/")
        
        
        
        let request = NSURLRequest (url: url! as URL)
        webView.frame = self.view.frame;
        
        webView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
        
        
        
        
        let wurl = URL(string: "whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!")!
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(wurl, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(wurl)
        }

Comment: i use both webview and whatsapp code in viewDidLoad()

Comment: you cannot have whatsapp code in viewdid load it has to be in shouldStartLoadWithRequest.

Comment: override func StartLoadWithRequest ?? like this ? in viewcontroller.swift ?

Comment: Yes you also have to set webview's delegate to your viewcontroller

Comment: i have used func shouldStartLoadWithRequest()  but when i click on share button on my webview page nothing happens

Comment: how to set webview delegate ? i have aded like this , ctrl + drag webview to viewcontroller and select delegate, i have to add code into view controller ?

Comment: wait i am drafting the answer

Comment: if (request.URL.scheme == "whatsapp") {
 error in this line

value of optional type 'URL?' not unwrapped, did you mean to use ! or '?'

Comment: Do you know swift or wat ?

Comment: Unwrap URL with !

Comment: i already tried it error has been gone, but webview not loading,,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124812/discussion-between-vishnuvarthan-and-ninder-chand).